# 7 in queue but the 'First Post' review is blank

Tags: support

I've just gone into the review area and the First Post queue is showing 7. I went into the queue and it's empty.

Ten minutes later the same is still happening, so I don't think all 7 were reviewed in the time it took me to click the link.

Is this a known issue? Do I need to report this as a problem, and if so, how?

Comment: It's also possible there is some caching at work here.

Comment: It's back to normal now.

Answer (score 1):

You might have set a filter, e.g. to see only "First Answers" - see
[image]

Comment: I haven't set a filter. It wasn't saying there were no items to review, it was just completely blank.